# How to ensure username and password match case sensitivity

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2019

While testing this code I have found out that it doesn't matter if it's uppercase or lowercase the check still passes. I've tried a couple of methods with EQUALS or .Equals(), but I just cant get my head around it.

```cs
if (isValid())
{                               
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\DAVER\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\LoginDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Username '" + txtBoxUserName.Text.Trim() +
                       "' AND Password '" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter sqlData = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        sqlData.Fill(data);
                        
        if (data.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            ControlID.txtBoxUserName = txtBoxUserName.Text;
    
            ControlID.txtPassword = txtPassword.Text;
            PopUp pop = new PopUp();
            this.Hide();
            pop.Show();
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username and/or Password Not Recognised!", "Error");
        }
```

Comment: Yikes! Use parameters. Hash password with a salt, use some strong hashing algorithm. Don't hardcode your connection string.

Comment: https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: You're missing the `=` to compare the Username and Password.  Also note that case sensitivity is determine by the DB collation which typically defaults to case insensitive.  So you'd need to pull back the values and then do a case sensitive check on them.

Comment: sorry, I'm very new to coding, so I am unsure how to do either

Comment: @TanveerBadar. im unsure how do i salt or hash the algorithm?

Comment: @Brother_Able In the short snippet of code you've presented, you've created vulnerabilites around SQL Injection, storage of passwords etc. Code like this is a hacker's dream. I'm a developer of over 30 years experience. I would never consider implementing my own login/authentication system and nor should you. This is a solved problem with hundreds of examples of how to do this correctly.

Comment: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: If you are very new to coding, very good.  But user authentication is maybe not that kind of task a beginner should start with.